# Separate collection of lists by without losing the order?

Tags: list, split, prolog

Is there some way in SWI Prolog to separate a list of lists e.g. of following form:

```
[[left, 1], [left, 2], [right, 3], [right, 4]]
```

into **two lists** separated by the first values, in the example:

`[[left, 1], [left, 2]]` and `[[right, 3], [right, 4]]`

Comment: Underspecified problem. What do you expect for `[[left, 1], [left, 2], [right, 3], [right, 4],[left 5]]`?

Comment: I expect two lists `A` and `B` in the output, means `A =  [left, 1], [left, 2]` and  `B = [right, 3], [right, 4],[left 5]`

Comment: So `[left,5]` is now in the second group?

Comment: No, cant edit it sorry

Comment: Your final clarification should be in your question (such that these comments become superfluous)

Comment: Marked it bold.

Comment: See: [partition/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=partition/4)

Comment: What if the given list is `[[left,1], [left,2], [right,3], [right,4], [left,5], [middle,7]]`? Shouldn't we split *this* particular list into **three** lists rather than two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
separate_lists(Lst, SplitA, SplitB) :-
    Lst = [[K, V]|T],
    SplitA = [[K, V]|TailA],
    separate_lists_(T, K, TailA, SplitB).
    
separate_lists_([], _, [], []).
separate_lists_([[K, V]|T], K, SplitA, SplitB) :-
    !,
    % Same key - still looping through list A
    SplitA = [[K, V]|SplitA0],
    separate_lists_(T, K, SplitA0, SplitB).
% Put remainder in list B
separate_lists_([[K, V]|T], _PrevK, [], [[K, V]|T]).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- separate_lists([[left, 1], [left, 2], [right, 3], [right, 4]], A, B).
A = [[left,1],[left,2]],
B = [[right,3],[right,4]].

?- separate_lists([[left, 1], [left, 2], [right, 3], [right, 4], [left, 5]], A, B).
A = [[left,1],[left,2]],
B = [[right,3],[right,4],[left,5]].
```